# JSTL loop not working

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have the following code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSTL</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forTokens items="Zara,nuha,roshy" delims="," var="name">
   <c:out value="${name}"/><p>
</c:forTokens>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it, I am getting a blank page. 
Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare the core taglib at the top of the page. Look at the generated HTML code, and you'll see `<c:forTokens>` and `<c:out>` verbatim in the generated HTML code, which is an indication that the JSP container considered them as pure text, and not as JSP tags.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

And you also forgot to add the jar(s) of the JSTL in your webapp. Follow the instructions of the [JSTL tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

Comment: when I add it, I am getting 500 error with the following in the console

"The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

Comment: I am using TomCat 6. Which version should I download?

Comment: [Its home page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/index.html) says, in the first line: *Apache Tomcat version 6.0 implements the Servlet 2.5 and JavaServer Pages 2.1 specifications*. And the JSTL tag info details which versions of the JSTL are compatible with which version of the specs. The servlet version you're using is also in the web.xml of your webapp.